# How to execute selenium webdriver test cases parallely in multiple browser using IntelliJ + JUnit + Java

Tags: java, junit, cross-browser-testing

I wanted to run the test scripts in multiple browsers. Ideally Chrome, FFox, IE11, Opera and Safari.

How would be ideal to be able to run that?

Here's my stack.

IntelliJ + JUnit + Java

Any ideas, information, insights, links to third party tutorials, etc... is much appreciated.

Comment: have you resolved your issue?

Comment: I'm still having issue in open Opera. I'm in a proxy based place, probably is that. Soon as I get around it and working I'll share the findings.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest to use the latest version of the `maven-surefire-plugin`. This is the config I am using which works fine

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>all</parallel>
        <threadCount>10</threadCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Heads Up :

- Do not use non final static variables
- If you really need them you could wrap them in a InheritableThreadLocal instance